# Sketch the surface of $y^2 +4z^2 = 4$

Tags: conic-sections, surfaces, quadrics

To clarify, the standard form of the above equation is in the form of an ellipsoid. However, as it is independent of its $x$ values, may I know if the sketch of the surface is still an ellipsoid or will it look differently?

Comment: it is an ellipse in the YZ-plane but if you insist in an IR^3 visualization then it is a tube or cylinder of elliptical shape

Comment: To have an ellipsoid, none of the coefficients in the standard-form equation can be zero. See the tables in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric#Euclidean_space.